# Задачка на алгоритм для ниндзя

Tags: алгоритм

Уже полторы недели небольшими набегами думаем, как её решить. Может быть, тут кто-то сможет :)

**Даны** два массива натуральных чисел: `x` и `y` (оба массива неубывающие), и натуральное число `Q`.

**Найти** такие числа из этих массивов, что `x[i] * y[j]` максимально близко к `Q`.

Сложность не должна превышать `O(n+m)`, где `n` и `m` — размеры массивов.

Comment: **x[i] * y[i]** здесь нет опечатки?

Comment: Я не знаю, считать ли это опечаткой. Тут я имел ввиду, что оба элемента должны быть с разных массивов. Спасибо, что заметили, это могло в дальнейшем запутать:)

Comment: Должно быть как-то так, чтобы не запутать ?  

    x[k] * y[m]

Comment: Да.Это подойдет. Есть мысли по решению? Пытались идти с разных сторон обоих массивов, вроде решение неплохое, не могу понять как там дальше быть.

Comment: сложность в том что скажем в массивах [2,3,6,8,9,11,99] [1,6,7,9,48,49,50] и Q=97 мы получаем два разных правильных ответа и оба не равны Q ?

Comment: Мне кажется перый попавшийся правильный сойдет. Вы знаете как решить?

Comment: мы не знаем, до того как переберем все произведения, нет ли у нас точного попадания. решать стал бы отсечением массива ответов по минимальному расстоянию от Q, т.е. при нахождении меньшего (либо равного предыдущему) ненулевого расстояния  - предыдущий ответ считать неверным, при нулевом расстоянии выдавать ответ,  если массивы закончились, то брать текущий ответ. бежать в разные стороны смысла нет особого, искомые значения могут быть где угодно (скажем в моем примере 98 может "оказаться" 97). 

я не думал долго, так-что оставлю комментом.

Comment: *когда текущее произведение меньше Q, то находим какое произведение ближе к искомому- текущее, предыдущее или ранее сохраненное как наиближайшее*

а зачем сравнивать с предыдущим ? оно по любому более далеко чем *ранее сохраненное как наиближайшее* 

или что мы делаем когда оно ближе, сразу сдвигаем ?

Comment: @eicto не обязательно, например текущая ситуация  
[..., 15, ...] и [..., 4, 5, ...] Q=74  
15\*5 = 75 - предыдущее значение  
15\*4 = 60 - текущее значение, которое меньше Q

Comment: ReinRaus, когда произедение становится меньше Q, мы сдвигаем счетчик на втором массиве право, а на первом снова уходим в хвост, я правильно понял?

Comment: @alex91: нет, продолжаем с той же позиции, в этом фишка.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/a7KQT/ пытался реализовать, получается ерунда, либо я не понимаю что делаем *когда текущее произведение меньше Q* либо что-то не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просматриваем один массив с головы, другой с хвоста.
Передвигаемся по второму массиву из хвоста в голову, сохраняя два значения- текущее произведение и предыдущее
когда текущее произведение меньше Q, то находим какое произведение ближе к искомому- текущее, предыдущее или ранее сохраненное как наиближайшее
сдвигаем первый массив из головы в хвост на одну позицию и повторяем  движение по второму массиву, пока опять текущее произведение не станет меньше Q
Когда первый массив будет весь пройден то наиближайшее будет найдено при сложности i+j

---

**UPD**
Реализация на JavaScript  http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/nK5Nz/
**UPD2**
Исправил ошибки и недочеты кода

Comment: @ReinRaus, но я так понимаю ответ "ближайшее", это одно из значений массива. У Вас же в массиве нет числа 96, а результат именно оно.

Comment: а как на результат влияют значения arr1 ? i - это ключи в вашей реализации. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nK5Nz/4/ :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nK5Nz/5/ вот исправленная версия, единственное, она почему-то выдает undefined при Q>9802

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nK5Nz/9/ крайне не верно работает.

Comment: @eicto, простите, торопился и не везде заменил **i** на **arr1[i]**  
Поправил код

Answer (score 1):

Перебрал алгоритм [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus), исправил ошибки.

```
function nearest(arr1,arr2,Q){
  var _i=arr1.length-1,   
      _j=arr2.length-1,
      mind=Math.abs(Q-arr1[_i]*arr2[_j]);
  for (var i=0,j=arr2.length-1;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    while (j>0){
      d=Math.abs(Q-arr1[i]*arr2[j]);
      if(d<mind){   
        mind=d;
        _i=i;     
        _j=j;
      }
      if(arr1[i]*arr2[j]<Q)break;  
      j--; 
    }
  }
  return arr1[_i]*arr2[_j];
}
```

[попробовать](http://jsfiddle.net/nK5Nz/7/)